# read data set in r and change the format

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data set for US precipitation. it has latitude , longitude ,and rainfall amount. it has the following format:

```
       lon -124   -125  -126 -127 -128
   lat 45  120   110    NA   230  145
       44  NA    130    205  240  195
       43  120   110    NA   235  185
       42  170   140    204   NA  155
```

this is the link for data set:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xxy2ospr9xvy8n/Pmaxupscaled.csv

I want to convert it to this format using R:

```
    precipitation  lat   lon       
    120            45    -124
    110            45    -125
    NA             45    -126
```

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto; It has .csv format.

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto; I added the dput format.

Comment: The `dput` entry seems incomplete, it doesn't work at my end.

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto; I add the link for data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answers are more than maxed out with "reshape2", here's an option in base R:

```
a <- read.csv("path/to/Pmaxupscaled.csv", check.names = FALSE)
out <- cbind(lat = a[, 1], setNames(stack(a[-1]), c("precip", "lon")))
head(out)
#    lat precip  lon
# 1 45.0  77.63 -105
# 2 42.5  76.15 -105
# 3 40.0  72.18 -105
# 4 37.5  78.60 -105
# 5 35.0  80.93 -105
# 6 32.5  87.29 -105
tail(out)
#      lat precip lon
# 99  40.0 136.05 -75
# 100 37.5     NA -75
# 101 35.0     NA -75
# 102 32.5     NA -75
# 103 30.0     NA -75
# 104 27.5     NA -75
```

---

For the record, this would be my approach with "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)
a <- read.csv("path/to/Pmaxupscaled.csv", check.names = FALSE)
names(a)[1] <- "lat"
out <- melt(a, id.vars="lat", value.name="precip", variable.name="lon")
head(out)
#    lat precip  lon
# 1 45.0  77.63 -105
# 2 42.5  76.15 -105
# 3 40.0  72.18 -105
# 4 37.5  78.60 -105
# 5 35.0  80.93 -105
# 6 32.5  87.29 -105
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Could you please also tell me how I can delete those rows with "NA" values?

Comment: @user3000796, starting from the "out <-" step, `out <- out[complete.cases(out),]` should do it.

Comment: That was great Anand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use the 'reshape2' package -

```
library(reshape2)
df<- read.table(textConnection('
lat -124   -125  -126 -127 -128
45  120   110    NA   230  145
44  NA    130    205  240  195
43  120   110    NA   235  185
42  170   140    204   NA  155'), header = TRUE)

df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = 'lat')
```

You will also need to get a workaround for your original column names. R doesn't like numerical column names. This could be a workaround in this specific case -

```
 df2$variable  <- gsub(x = df2$variable, pattern = "X\\.", replacement = "")
```

Comment: @ Cordoremifa; I used your command line and I put my data inside ' ' becuse that was just part of my data and I run it and I got this error: Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 2 elements

Comment: That error message seems pretty clear, Line 1 in your data has different number of elements (columns) than other lines which seems to have 2 values. If you look at what I've put inside the '', you will see that I haven't exactly copy pasted your data. You need to do something similar.

Comment: Yes I did exactly the same thing. I used notepad to copy and then paste it in R. Then there is no space between variables I think that is the reason . How you copy and paste the data?

Comment: Let me approach this from the other direction, can you convert your dataset to the format I've started with (manually or automatically)?

Comment: this is the link to the data:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xxy2ospr9xvy8n/Pmaxupscaled.csv

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a super `reshape2` user but this is what works for me.

```
library(reshape2)
a <- read.csv("~/Documents/Pmaxupscaled.csv")

# Convert to matrix
a <- as.matrix(a)

# Replace row names with the values from the first column
dimnames(a)[[1]] <- a[, 1]

# Drop the first column
a <- a[, -1]

# Melt the matrix into a data frame.
b <- melt(a, varnames = c("Lat", "Lon"))

# Get rid of "X."
b$Lon <- gsub("X\\.", "", b$Lon)

# Format longitude as negative number
b$Lon <- as.numeric(b$Lon)
b$Lon <- -1 * b$Lon

# Rename precipitation column
names(b)[3] <- "precipitation"
```